# How to implement custom bubble bottom navigation animation

Tags: android, kotlin, animation, android-animation, bottomnavigationview

I have tried this library - https://github.com/gauravk95/bubble-navigation
I don't think this can be achieved by transition drawable as the previous tab is selected during the transition. Only the current tab can be animated using the TransitionDrawable.

Also, the corner tabs have different background animation.

[Link to animation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mVfGE.jpg)